# Uno Platform BottomNavBar uncheck selected item

Tags: uno-platform

I have an app that uses a bottomnavbar from uno-material.  The bar is working fine.  I also have a settings button up towards top.  When the user selects the button- it changes color.  What I am trying to do is to "unselect" the item that is currently selected on the bottomnavbar- so the user will know they are using the settings button.  I know the bottomnavbar from uno-material uses togglebuttons- so that is why I tried that path.  Here is what I have tried so far:

XAML:

```xml
 <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="settingsButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemBackground}" Click="settingsButton_Click">
                <SymbolIcon x:Name="settingIcon" Symbol="Setting" Foreground="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemForeground}" >
                   
                </SymbolIcon>
            </Button>
         
        </StackPanel>



        <controls:BottomNavigationBar 
            x:Name="BottomNavBar" 
            Loaded="bottomNavView_Loaded">
            <controls:BottomNavigationBar.Items >
                <controls:BottomNavigationBarItem Label="Home" tag="HomeView" Click="OnClick" Padding.right="2" >
                    <controls:BottomNavigationBarItem.Icon>
                        <PathIcon  
                            Data=""/>
                    </controls:BottomNavigationBarItem.Icon>

                </controls:BottomNavigationBarItem>

                <controls:BottomNavigationBarItem Label="Event" tag="event" Click="OnClick" Padding.Left="2" Padding.right="2">
                    <controls:BottomNavigationBarItem.Icon>
                        <PathIcon
                            Data=""/>
                    </controls:BottomNavigationBarItem.Icon>

                </controls:BottomNavigationBarItem>

        
            </controls:BottomNavigationBar.Items>
            
        </controls:BottomNavigationBar>
```

Code Behind:

```cs
private void settingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            this.settingIcon.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground"] as SolidColorBrush;
            this.BottomNavBar.SelectedItem.isChecked = false;
            this.BottomNavView_Navigate("settings");
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original approach does not work, as the code prevents unselecting the selected item. The proper solution will look like this:

```cs
private void settingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SettingIcon.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground"] as SolidColorBrush;
    BottomNavBar.SelectedItem = null;       
}
```

Which is in line with other "list" controls. Unfortunately setting `SelectedItem` to `null` is currently not possible in `BottomNavigationBar` so I have created a PR to [fix this here](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Themes/pull/565). It should be merged soon

Comment: Thank you! I certainly prefer your approach to my solution below.  I will keep an eye on it when it gets merged.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm I saw the the change is now merged and I am able to use it as specified.  Thank you again!

Comment: Perfect, glad it helped :-) ! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured out a way that works- but I am not real fond of it.  If someone else has a better solution- please post.  Instead of "unselecting" the item- I overwrote the color. In the onClick event/Navigate Method- I set the color manually.  It is ugly in my opinion- but it seems to work and be responsive.  Here is the updated code:

```
private void BottomNavView_Navigate(string navItemTag)
{
 if (this.settingsButtonPressed)
                {
                    this.settingIcon.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["NavigationViewItemForeground"] as SolidColorBrush;
                    this.settingsButtonPressed = !this.settingsButtonPressed;
                   
                }
                this.selectedNavItem.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground"] as SolidColorBrush;
//do navigation here
}



private void settingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            this.settingsButtonPressed = true;
            this.settingIcon.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground"] as SolidColorBrush;
            
            this.selectedNavItem.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed"] as SolidColorBrush;
           this.BottomNavView_Navigate("settings");
            
        }
```